# `getLeft()` returns zero in `onWindowFocusChanged()`

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a separate class `Answer` which extends `ImageView`. This object is programatically added to the container view and then position initialisation method is called in `onWindowFocusChanged()` - this method sets correct margins and layout parameters and turns visibility on. Then I try to get Answer's initial X position by calling `getLeft()`. No matter if this is called from within Answers class `this.getLeft()` or from main activity `answer_object1.getLeft()` it still returns zero.

Why is that?

If I add Image view via XML and call 'getLeft()' in `onWindowFocusChanged()` it returns correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLeft()` will return you the actual value only after layout step will complete and `onLayout` of your `Answer` will be called. So, to record the initial position of your view it's better to do so in `onLayout`.

Now speaking of `onWindowFocusChanged()` - documentation makes no promises on whether this method will be called before `onLayout` or after, so it is not the best place to record the initial position of your view.